# Submit multiple values of a form using AJAX (but no jQuery) - XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Normally I'd use jQuery for this, but to cut a long story short, on this I can't.

I've successfully submitted a form via AJAX which has only one element of a form, like this:

```
<div id="response"></div>

<form onsubmit="submitStuff(this.datatosend.value);this.reset();return false;">
    <input id="datatosend" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function submitStuff(e) {
        if (e == "") {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "";
            return
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "sumbitData.php?data=" + e, true);
        xmlhttp.send()
    }
</script>
```

Now say I have this form:

```
<form onsubmit="????????????????????;this.reset();return false;">
    <input id="datatosend1" type="text" />
    <input id="datatosend2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How do I do the same, submitting both values?

I'm a bit new to Javascript, especially 'pure' Javascript so please be a bit patient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up the string

```
var data1 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("datatosend1").value);
var data2 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("datatosend2").value);
var url = "sumbitData.php?data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I was being slow it would appear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the form values and make a string to attach to the url:

```
    var child=document.getElementById(form_id).getElementsByTagName('input');
    var data=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<child.length;i++){
        data.push(child[i].id + '='+ encodeURIComponent(child[i].value));
        }
    data='?' + data.join('&');
```